# SQL - JOIN on a table that matches multiple rows and put into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query with multiple left joins but one of the joins is a little complicated.  Using the examples below, I need to output a single row for each ID in the first table.  The second table has multiple rows for each ID and consists of parameter name and value pairs which I am trying to output as shown at the very bottom.  I only care about 3 specific parameter names.

I have multiple issues at the moment.  One is my join lets me add "value" however it creates multiple rows for bob jones when I only want one row.  The second is I want just those 3 specific param names and to ignore the rest.  If an ID doesn't have a value just return NULL or leave blank.

```
ID   first    last
1    bob      jones
2    joe      dirt

num  param    value
1    color    green
1    shape    circle
1    food     apple
2    color    red
2    drink    water
2    animal   dog
```

Desired result

```
ID   first    last    color    shape    drink
1    bob      jones   green    circle   NULL
2    joe      dirt    red      NULL     water
```

Comment: Is this mysql or sql server?

Answer (score -1):

Group the data by user and use conditional aggregation to get the values of each user

```
select t1.id, t1.first, t1.last,
       max(case when t2.param = 'color' then t2.value end) as color,
       max(case when t2.param = 'shape' then t2.value end) as shape,
       max(case when t2.param = 'drink' then t2.value end) as drink
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.first, t1.last
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you!!!!!!!!!!!